# Иконки для уведомлений Notification.Builder

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

Подскажите, какого формата и какого размера должны быть иконки для методов 
setSmallIcon()  и  setLargeIcon()   и где их можно скачать? Или есть ли в Android стандартные иконки и где они лежат ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Андроид студии по умолчанию есть иконки, о том как их добавить можно узнать [здесь](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html). Также есть очень хороший и удобный [плагин](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer) который добавляет огромное количесвто иконок и позволяет импортировать свои изображения в папку `drawable`. На счет размера вам не стоит беспокоиться так как андроид студия создаст несколько иконок с разными разрешениями и сама выберет какой размер фотографии выбрать в зависимости от разрешения экрана устройства.

Answer (score 1):

Для `setSmallIcon()` требуется иконка размером 24х24px, белый цвет на прозрачном фоне.

Для `setLargeIcon` иконки должны быть такие же как иконка приложения - любой цвет и размеры от 48x48px и далее размеры для 1.5х, 2х, 3х, 4х.